# place select elements next to each other

Tags: html, css

How do I position two or more  tags text to each other? I think the issue is just one simple tag in the CSS but I have been looking at forums for a good hour now and can't find a solution. all I want is something like this:

BOX   BOX   BOX

But what I'm getting is that the modules are stacked on top of eatch other rather than side to side. This is the core I've used so far:

```css
.apply_form-birthdatemonth {
  position: relative;
  font-size:20px;
  text-align: left;
  left:37%;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.input-month {
  display:block;
  width: 10%;
  border: 1px solid rgb(70, 70, 70);
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}

.apply_form-birthdateday {
  position: relative;
  font-size:20px;
  text-align: left;
  left:48%;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  flex: 1;
}

.input-day{
  display:block;
  width: 10%;
  border: 1px solid rgb(70, 70, 70);
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  left:48%;
}

.apply_form-birthdateyear {
  position: relative;
  font-size:20px;
  text-align: left;
  left:59%;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.input-year{
  display:block;
  width: 10%;
  border: 1px solid rgb(70, 70, 70);
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="apply_form-birthdatemonth">
            <select class="input-month">
                <option>Month</option>
                <option>January</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="apply_form-birthdateday">
            <select class="input-day">
                <option>Day</option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="apply_form-birthdateyear">
            <select class="input-year">
                <option>Year</option>
                <option>2021</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: `div` has a default display of `block` that causes it to spread on the whole "line". If you change it to `display: inline-block` you'll get the divs in the same line while maintaining the ability to set width and height if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you check out [CSS Grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_grid) - it's quickly becoming (if not already) the *de facto* standard for aligning elements in the way you're describing! Hopefully this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

use `display: inline` instead of `display: block`

Answer (score 0):

The oldschool way would be to set **.apply_form-birthdatemonth**'s *display* propperty to *inline-block* [more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) the second and more modern way is to set the **parent div's** *display* property to *flex* as you can see [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and the third way, which could be considered an overkill is to set yet again the **parent div's** *display* property to *grid* [more here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Answer (score 0):

Simple Implementation using Grid.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}
.apply_form-birthdatemonth {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  left: 37%;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.input-month {
  display: block;
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid rgb(70, 70, 70);
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}

.apply_form-birthdateday {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  left: 48%;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  flex: 1;
}

.input-day {
  display: block;
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid rgb(70, 70, 70);
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  left: 48%;
}

.apply_form-birthdateyear {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  left: 59%;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.input-year {
  display: block;
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid rgb(70, 70, 70);
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="apply_form-birthdatemonth">
        <select class="input-month">
          <option>Month</option>
          <option>January</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="apply_form-birthdateday">
        <select class="input-day">
          <option>Day</option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="apply_form-birthdateyear">
        <select class="input-year">
          <option>Year</option>
          <option>2021</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way of positioning object in 2 dimension is by using flexbox and you can check that out here [flexbox mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox). And for objects in 3 dimension is by grid also check it here [grids mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids)